# some image files cannot be modified on Android Q

Tags: image, android-intent

I have one image editor app, which can modify image files. On Android 10, it calls Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to show image files on the phone, and let user to select one to edit.The problem is some image files cannot be modified, when they are modified , the app exits automatically. These image files seem to be other apps' private images or system images. Is there any way to hide these image files when Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is called?

Comment: Image like .img or .png | jpg | etc?

Comment: yes, they are png or jpg, and if you modify them, can cause app exits automatically , no error messages output

Comment: Which App is it?